# How to compress html output in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, html-compression

I know Twig has a {% spaceless %} filter, but it only removes spaces between html tags.

I need to return a single line of html for every page in the site. I have a regexp that can deal with that, but I don't know where to use it in sf2, since everything happens automagically.

I think I have to register a new templating engine, or add a twig extension, but I couldn't find enough documentation about the subject, so I'm stuck

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run your regex on all view output, you can hook into the `kernel.response` event that is dispatched by the Symfony2 framework.

From the section on [kernel.response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-response-event):

> The purpose of this event is to allow other systems to modify or
>   replace the Response object after its creation:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();

    // ... modify the response object
}
```

I would recommend reading the [Internals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html) chapter for even more details.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I don't think the spaceless filter is ment to do that, so I can't report it as a bug. It only removes spaces between html tags.

Comment: Sometimes it even fails to do that, I'm seeing many newlines in my code, between html tags, so I just want to run my own regexp as I always did, but I don't know how to do it in this framework.

Comment: The answer was the 'internals' part, thanks. I got my single line html output now =p

Comment: I'd say that spaceless is not a good solution. For example, <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Dashboard</span> is not the same as <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Dashboard</span> (note gap after closing i).

Comment: Good points by all. I've modified the answer to address the comments.